# Upcasting and Generics

Tags: generics, f#

I am honestly perplexed about this.
Why doesn't that work - aren't I explicitly telling that `'T` is indeed a `View`?

```
let foo<'T when 'T :> View> (v:'T):View = v

error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type View 
but here has type 'T
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> In many object-oriented languages, upcasting is implicit; in F#, the rules are slightly different. Upcasting is applied automatically when you pass arguments to methods on an object type. However, for let-bound functions in a module, **upcasting is not automatic**, unless the parameter type is declared as a flexible type.
>
> The `:>` operator performs a static cast, which means that the success of the cast is determined at compile time.

The minimal code would be

```
let foo<'T when 'T :> View> (v:'T):View = v :> _
```

Comment: Why not use a [flexible type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx)? `let foo (v : #View) = v :> View`